# Does the name of the prophet Muhammad appears in the Quran?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

Does the name of the prophet Muhammad appears in the original Al-Quran?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His name "Muhammad" appears in the Quran in:

[3:144](https://legacy.quran.com/3/144),
[33:40](https://legacy.quran.com/33/40),
[47:2](https://legacy.quran.com/47/2),
[48:29](https://legacy.quran.com/48/29)

His name "Ahmad" appears in:

[61:6](https://legacy.quran.com/61/6)

Other names and titles appear throughout the Quran.